# Name Error by python, name 'ArticleDetailView' is not defined

Tags: python, django, nameerror

This is the problem I have:

```
File "C:\simpleblog\ablog\myblog\urls.py", line 8, in <module>
    path('article/<int:pk>',ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
NameError: name 'ArticleDetailView' is not defined
```

my urls.py:

```
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import HomeView

    urlpatterns = [
        path('article/<int:pk>',ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
    ]
```

In my views.py I have clearly defined it, below is my views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
    from .models import Post

    class HomeView(ListView):
        model = Post
        template_name = 'home.html'

    class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Post
        template_name = 'article_details.html'
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specifically import `ArticleDetailView` as well:

```
from .views import HomeView, ArticleDetailView
```

Generally if you use a decent IDE, the software will show you that you are missing imports and will make a suggestion on how to solve it.